# hibernate and wampserver in port 81

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a dynamic web project in Java EE.
When I use "auto create database" with Hibernate, compilation doesn't give any exceptions just warnings and the database is not created.

In effect, I have changed the "wampserver's" port 80 to 81 because the IIS server is already on 80. In my `hibernate.cfg.xml`, I have put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:81/DB_TRANSPORT_CARGAISON</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>  

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2dll.auto">create</property>

    <mapping resource="dao/Cargaison.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="dao/Marchandise.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

The port 80, that you set to 81, is the port of the web server of wamp (i.e. the port of Apache, the **a** in wamp). What you must specify in the JDBC URL is the port of the MySQL database server: the **m** in wamp.

My guess is that you let it at its default value, so not specifying any port should work fine:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_TRANSPORT_CARGAISON
```